# NameError: name 'L1' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, global

Why is my code showing a "NameError: name 'L1' is not defined" error when I try to run it? It seems that I am missing something when I try to assign the list of values to the variable steps.

```
steps = (L1, R3, R1, L5, L2, L5, R4, L2, R2, R2, L2, R1, L5, R3, L4, L1, L2, R3, R5, L2, R5, L1, R2, L5, R4, R2, R2, L1, L1, R1, L3, L1, R1, L3, R5, R3, R3, L4, R4, L2, L4, R1, R1, L193, R2, L1, R54, R1, L1, R71, L4, R3, R191, R3, R2, L4, R3, R2, L2, L4, L5, R4, R1, L2, L2, L3, L2, L1, R4, R1, R5, R3, L5, R3, R4, L2, R3, L1, L3, L3, L5, L1, L3, L3, L1, R3, L3, L2, R1, L3, L1, R5, R4, R3, R2, R3, L1, L2, R4, L3, R1, L1, L1, R5, R2, R4, R5, L1, L1, R1, L2, L4, R3, L1, L3, R5, R4, R3, R3, L2, R2, L1, R4, R2, L3, L4, L2, R2, R2, L4, R3, R5, L2, R2, R4, R5, L2, L3, L2, R5, L4, L2, R3, L5, R2, L1, R1, R3, R3, L5, L2, L2, R5)
steps = steps.split(", ")

dir = 0
x,y = 0,0
turn, walk = 0, 0

for i in steps:
    turn = i[0]
    walk = i[1]
    if turn == "L":
        dir -= 1
    elif turn == "R":
        dir += 1
    if dir % 4 == 0:
        y += walk
    elif dir % 4 == 1:
        x += walk
    elif dir % 4 == 3:
        x -= walk
    elif (dir % 4 == 2):
        y -= walk

final = x.abs() + y.abs()
print(final)
```

Comment: I think you should reame your variables from `L1` to `"L1"` and so on. And your code should work.

Comment: You `.split()` steps, so should it be a string?, e.g. `steps = "L1, R3, ... R5"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has quite a few problems. The first problem is that `steps` should be a string and not a tuple of undefined variables, as addressed by others. Once this change is made you'll stumble into others, though.

The code below should resolve this problem and other discovered problems:

```
steps = "L1, R3, R1, L5, L2, L5, R4, L2, R2, R2, L2, R1, L5, R3, L4, L1, L2, R3, R5, L2, R5, L1, R2, L5, R4, R2, R2, L1, L1, R1, L3, L1, R1, L3, R5, R3, R3, L4, R4, L2, L4, R1, R1, L193, R2, L1, R54, R1, L1, R71, L4, R3, R191, R3, R2, L4, R3, R2, L2, L4, L5, R4, R1, L2, L2, L3, L2, L1, R4, R1, R5, R3, L5, R3, R4, L2, R3, L1, L3, L3, L5, L1, L3, L3, L1, R3, L3, L2, R1, L3, L1, R5, R4, R3, R2, R3, L1, L2, R4, L3, R1, L1, L1, R5, R2, R4, R5, L1, L1, R1, L2, L4, R3, L1, L3, R5, R4, R3, R3, L2, R2, L1, R4, R2, L3, L4, L2, R2, R2, L4, R3, R5, L2, R2, R4, R5, L2, L3, L2, R5, L4, L2, R3, L5, R2, L1, R1, R3, R3, L5, L2, L2, R5"
steps = steps.split(", ")

dir = 0
x,y = 0,0
turn, walk = 0, 0

for step in steps:
    turn = step[0]
    walk = int(step[1])
    if turn == "L":
        dir -= 1
    elif turn == "R":
        dir += 1
    if dir % 4 == 0:
        y += walk
    elif dir % 4 == 1:
        x += walk
    elif dir % 4 == 3:
        x -= walk
    elif (dir % 4 == 2):
        y -= walk

final = abs(x) + abs(y)
print(final)
```

**Output**

```
11
```

Comment: I was just thinking that. I'm upvoting it, since it's definitely a complete answer.